# jquery waves-effect not working when disable and enable button

Tags: jquery, materialize

Hi I have buttons using `waves-effect waves-light` in my class:

[image]

Then when I click it I disable and after I save data to server I enable again but something is not working because the button keeps the disable state util I hover again I can see it returns to normal style.

[image]

```
me.addClass('disabled');
            me.prop('disabled', true);
            me.html('<i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner" style="width: auto;height: auto; line-height: 1px; margin-right: 10px;"></i>Please wait');
```

This is how it looks after I enable again the button:

[image]

```
me.prop('disabled', false);
                    me.removeClass('disabled');
```

If I hover it then its style is reseted to normal. I'm sure is something about the class `waves-effect`.

> Any clue?